# Using gettext in PHP

Tags: php, internationalization, gettext

I'm working on open source software and thinking of using a gettext to localize the interface. The question is: is there a way for me not to add a gettext module dependency?

Since gettext support comes as a PHP module, I need to make all users install it. Is there an alternative for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I *think* `gettext` is compiled in in the vast majority of PHP installations. I have never seen one without it.

That said, Zend Framework's [Zend_Translate](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.translate.html) is truly package independent, and much more powerful than gettext. It can handle a number of dictionary formats, including gettext. It can be used as a standalone component. If you're starting with localization, it's definitely worth a look.

Comment: Well Zend_Translate is not really package independent, it's dependent on the entire Zend_Framework. :-)

Comment: @MarcoDemaio I've actually had some success ripping Zend_Translate out of the Zend_Framework. It's really only dependent on the autoloader, exception, and locale classes.

Answer (score 3):

Consider `gettext` as a legacy extension. PHP now supports the new ICU library. Look up the following classes: `Intl`, `Locale`, `MessageFormatter`.

Comment: for INTL class you must have php > 5.3 (or install intl as php pecl extension). ... shared hosting users most likely will have to use gettext.

Comment: What makes you say that gettext is a legacy ext.? Where did you get that from?

Comment: mmm. i'm looking through Intl docs and can't figure out how to do simple translation: english string to foreign string....  It was easy with gettext.

Comment: gettext is not a legacy extension. INTL is for L10N, gettext is for I18N. different purpose.

Answer (score 1):

There are two alternatives actually. [php-gettext](https://launchpad.net/php-gettext/) and [gettext.php](http://fossil.include-once.org/upgradephp/finfo/ext/gettext.php), both implemented in PHP userland so you can use them as fallback if the PHP native gettext extension is not compiled in.